# Wrong DNS cache on Windows Vista

Tags: networking, windows-vista, dns, cname

I'm in the process of developing website on Openshift. I've ordered an domain and set CNAME record to the address something-namespace.rhcloud.com as required in the Openshift docs.

My problem is that my brother was helping me with debugging the website during the development. From certain point, DNS just stopped working for him and I get the default non-existing webpage (generated by the company where I purchased the domain).

When I ask my friends to try the website, everything works for them, everything works for me as well (I'm in the different location then he is).

He is using Windows 7 so we tried

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and it didn't work

After that we tried

```
net stop dnscache
```

After few seconds, website is working for him, but that works just for few seconds and then we get the same error page again.

Could you please give me some advice where could we debug further? What can be happening?
We have also tried to contact his network provider, restarting router ... nothing helped so far.

Thank you very much

Comment: DNS propagation might take time. Try using 8.8.8.8 (google) as his DNS server, or maybe try manually adding the site in the hosts file.

Comment: from a command prompt, do a `nslookup yoursitename` and paste the results.

Comment: using google's DNS didn't came to my mind, that solves my problem for now :), thank you